# Proving the inverse of an application is continuous.

Tags: continuity, normed-spaces, operator-theory, inverse, inverse-function

**Exercise.** Consider the application $T: (\Bbb{K}^n, \| \cdot \|_\infty) \rightarrow (X, \| \cdot \|),$ where $\Bbb{K}$ is a field of scalars (either $\Bbb{C}$ or $\Bbb{R}$) and the norm $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ is the usual infinite norm in these fields. On the other hand, $X$ is some normed space equipped with the norm $\| \cdot \|$ with finite dimension $n \in \Bbb{N}$. Let $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ be a basis for the space $X$. The application is defined as follows:
$$ T(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n) = \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j e_j$$
Show that $T$ is a linear and topological isomorphism.

**My attempt.** To show that $T$ is a linear and topological isomorphism, one should prove that $T$ is linear, bijective, continuous and that it admits an inverse ($T^{-1}$) which is also continuous. I was able to prove that $T$ is linear, bijective and continuous. I omit the proofs for linearity and bijective since they are obvious by simple definitions. Follows the proof for continuity:

Recall the usual delta-epsilon definition for continuity:

$$ \forall \epsilon > 0, \, \exists \delta > 0 \, : \, \| \alpha - \alpha_0 \|_{\infty} < \delta \Rightarrow \| T\alpha - T\alpha_0 \| < \epsilon $$

Let $\alpha_0$ be an arbitrary element of $\Bbb{K}^n$. Then, $\forall \alpha \in \Bbb K:$
$$ \| T\alpha - T\alpha_0 \| = \| \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j e_j - \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{0j} e_j \| \leqslant \sum_{j=1}^n \|(\alpha_j - \alpha_{0j})e_j\| = \sum_{j=1}^n |\alpha_j - \alpha_{0j}|\| e_j \| \leqslant \sum_{j=1}^n \|\alpha - \alpha_0 \|_{\infty}\|e_j\| $$
Since $\| \alpha - \alpha_0\|_{\infty}$ doesn't depend on $j$, we just remove it from the sum and we get:
$$ \|\alpha - \alpha_0\|_{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n\|e_j\| < \delta \sum_{j=1}^n\|e_j\| < \epsilon \Rightarrow \delta < \frac{\epsilon}{\sum_{j=1}^n \|e_j\|}.$$
Thus, taking  $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{\sum_{j=1}^n \|e_j\|}$ on the usual delta-epsilon definition of continuity is enough to show that $T$ is, indeed continuous. Here, note that $\sum_{j=1}^n \|e_j\| \neq 0$ (otherwise, the basis wouldn't be linearly independent).

Now, the only thing that's left is the proof that $T^{-1}$ is continuous. I am having some trouble doing this. Does anyone have a hint?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: All linear maps on finite dimensional spaces are continuous. You can search MSE for a proof.

Comment: @geetha290krm I know that, but I was trying to prove this without using that theorem. Is there a way to prove what I want assuming I don't have knowledge of that theorem?

Comment: I think you will be forced to reproduce  the proof of that theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@roro  I see your point (this was too long for a comment) $$\lvert \lvert T^{-1}(x)\rvert \rvert_{\infty} =\lvert \lvert T^{-1}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}e_{i} \rvert \rvert_{\infty} =\lvert \lvert \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{i} T^{-1}e_{i} \rvert \rvert_{\infty} \leq  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lvert \lvert   (x_{i} T^{-1}e_{i} \rvert \rvert_{\infty} \leq \max_{1\leq i\leq n}\lvert \lvert  T^{-1}e_{i} \rvert \rvert_{\infty}  \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lvert   x_{i}  \rvert $$,this proves that $T^{-1}$ is continuous (in fact this proves continuity at zero but for linear maps this is equivalent to continuity everywher) ,when $X$ is endowed with the norm $\lvert \lvert .\rvert \rvert_{1}: x\to \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lvert   (x_{i} \rvert $.Now all u need is to show that $\lvert \lvert .\rvert \rvert_{1}$ and $\lvert \lvert .\rvert \rvert$ are equivalent, because replacing a norm by an equivalent one does't alter continuity(In fact all norms are equivalent for finite dimensional normed spaces).another approach is to prove that $T$ is bounded below,$$\exists M>0,\forall a\in \mathbb{K}^{n} ;\lvert \lvert  a \rvert \rvert_{\infty}=1,\lvert \lvert  Ta \rvert \rvert \geq M$$.Suppose to the contrary that no such $M$ exists,the there is a sequence of unit vectors $a_{n}$ such that  $\lvert \lvert  Ta_{n}\rvert \rvert \to 0$,since the unit sphere of $\mathbb{K}^{n}$ is compact ,we can extract a convergent subsequence to a vector $a$( which I still denote $a_{n}$) ,so $$\lvert \lvert \lvert  Ta \rvert \rvert=\lim_{n\to \infty}\lvert \lvert  Ta_{n}\rvert \rvert = 0$$ ,this is impossible , since $T$ is injective and $\lvert \lvert  a \rvert \rvert=1$,hence $$\forall x\in X,\lvert \lvert  T^{-1}(x) \rvert \rvert_{\infty} \leq \frac{1}{M} \lvert \lvert x\lvert \rvert $$ which proves that $T^{-1}$ is continuous

Comment: This doesn't follow my point. I didn't use a generalization of the concept norm equivalence. As a matter fact, I am supposed to prove norm equivalence from the result I want to prove, so it makes no sense using it to prove this result.

Comment: The second approach looks more viable, but one should show that a linear operator bounded below admits a continuous inverse

Comment: @roro this is what I did! The last inequality is exactly the continuity of the inverse. In general if $S:E\to F$ is a Linear map between normed spaces, then $S$ is continuous iff $\exists a>0\forall x\in E, \lvert \lvert Sx\rvert \rvert \leq a \lvert \lvert x\rvert \rvert $, in my proof $a:=frac{1}{M}$

Comment: That's correct! Sorry for my dumbness... And thanks for your patience! Really clear answer.

Comment: @roro u are welcome.

Comment: Just one further question (if possible): When you play by contradiction, assuming no such $M$ exists, why should there exist a sequence of vectors $a_n$ such that $\| Ta_n \| \rightarrow 0$ ?

Comment: let's negate the assertion:$$\exists M>0,\forall a\in \mathbb{K}^{n} ;\lvert \lvert  a \rvert \rvert_{\infty}=1,\lvert \lvert  Ta \rvert \rvert \geq M$$  $$\forall M>0,\exists a\in \mathbb{K}^{n} ;\lvert \lvert  a \rvert \rvert_{\infty}=1,\lvert \lvert  Ta \rvert \rvert <M$$,now taking $M=\frac{1}{n}$,will give us a sequence of unit vectors $a_{n}$ satisfying :$$\forall m\in \mathbb{N} ;\lvert \lvert  a_{m} \rvert \rvert_{\infty}=1,\lvert \lvert  Ta_{m} \rvert \rvert < \frac{1}{m}$$

Answer (score 1):

All linear maps are continous provided the domain is a finite dimensioanl normed space,to see this u can apply the triangle inequality(which is exactly what u did in your proof), or remark that an injective linear map must be bounded below on the unit sphere(since it is compact in the finite dimensional case),the constant involved being the inverse of the norm of the inverse .To prove the continuity of the inverse ,simply u remark that the inverse of a linear map is linear, and your apply exactly the argument u used to prove contintuity of $T^{-1}$ instead of $T$.

Comment: It is not clear to me how the same argument I used for the continuity of $T$ works for the continuity of $T^{-1}$. How would one find the norm $\| \cdot \|$ of $X$ while working with the norm $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$ of $\Bbb K^n$?