# "Different" way of proving every norm is equivalent in finite dimensional vector space?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, operator-theory

It certainly is easy to find as many proofs as you want for the equivalence of any two norms in a finite dimensional vector space.

I was wondering what is the relationship between homeomorphisms and the equivalence of any two norms in a finite dimensional vector space.

This question urged to me since I am doing a worksheet that asked to to show that the mapping $T:(\Bbb K^n, \| \cdot \|_\infty) \rightarrow (X,\| \cdot \|)$ is a homeomorphism (more details can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568823/proving-the-inverse-of-an-application-is-continuous)) and afterwards to prove that any two norms on a finite dimensional space $X$ are equivalent, based on this result.

**Formal exercise.** Show that in a finite-dimensional vector space $X$, every two norms are equivalent, using [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568823/proving-the-inverse-of-an-application-is-continuous).

**My attempt of resolution.** Let $X$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and let $\|.\|_\beta$ and $\| \cdot \|_\gamma$ be two norms defined on $X$. Since $X$ is finite-dimensional, let $\{e_1\dots,e_n\}$ be a basis for $X$ and define a third norm on $X$ as follows:

Given $x \in X$ we can write: $$ x = \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_je_j,$$
for some scalars $\alpha_j \in \Bbb K, \forall j \in \{1,\dots,n\}.$ Set
$$ \| x \|_\infty = \max\{|\alpha_j|: j \in \{1,\dots,n\}\}$$
This is the exact same norm used for $\Bbb K^n$ in the previous result I linked. By transitivity, it suffices to show that both $\| \cdot \|_\beta$ and $\| \cdot \|_\gamma$ are equivalent to $\| \cdot \|_\infty$. This is easy to do (I will omit it here) using norm properties (triangle inequality and homogeneity).

Now, one could finish this proof in the usual way - i.e. - considering the unit sphere $S = \{x \in X : \| x \|_\infty = 1\}$ and applying some topological arguments.

I just don't see where I am applying the result I linked... Does it allow me to make some kind of shortcut? I am not really familiar with homeomorphisms so maybe this is way easier than what I think. So, basically, what I want to do is to use the linked result to somehow help me proving this. I believe that the infinite norm definition has to stick around, but I don't see how to relate it with the homeomorphism.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The result you want to use](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568823) is: for any $n$-dimensional $\Bbb K$-vector space $X$ ($\Bbb K=\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$) any linear bijection $\Bbb K^n\to X$ is an homeomorphism $(\Bbb{K}^n, \| \cdot \|_\infty) \rightarrow (X, \| \cdot \|),$ where $\| \cdot \|$ is an arbitrary norm on $X.$

Let $T:\Bbb K^n\to X$ be a linear bijection. Then, using this result twice, $T:(\Bbb{K}^n, \| \cdot \|_\infty)\to(X, \| \cdot \|_\beta)$ and $T:(\Bbb{K}^n, \| \cdot \|_\infty)\to(X, \| \cdot \|_\gamma)$ ar both homeomorphims hence by composition, $\mathrm{id}_X:(X, \| \cdot \|_\beta)\to(X, \| \cdot \|_\gamma)$ is a homeomorphism, i.e. $ \|_\gamma$ and $\cdot \|_\beta$ are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Consider teh identity map $I:(X,\lvert \lvert \rvert \rvert_{\infty})\to (X,\lvert \lvert \rvert \rvert_{\alpha})$,it is a linear map which is continous,this is inverse is also is continous,but the continuity is exactly the inequality giving equivalence of norms .$$ \lvert \lvert I(x)\rvert \rvert_{\alpha} \leq \lvert \lvert x \rvert  \rvert_{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lvert \lvert e_{i}\rvert \rvert_{\alpha}$$ So
$$\lvert \lvert x \rvert \rvert_{\alpha} \leq M \lvert \lvert x\rvert \rvert_{\infty}$$Where $M=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lvert \lvert e_{i}\rvert \rvert_{\alpha}$,Now the continuity of the inverse means ,there is some $N$ such that
$$\lvert \lvert I^{-1}(x) \rvert \rvert_{\infty}=\lvert \lvert x \rvert \rvert_{\infty} \leq N \lvert \lvert x\rvert \rvert_{\alpha}$$ Combinig both inequalities gives us the equivalence .

Comment: Where do you apply the fact that $\Bbb K^n$ with the norm $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ is homeomorphic to any normed space $X$ with some norm $\| \cdot \|_X$ ?

Comment: @roro I used implicitely the result that $\mathbb{K}^{n},\lvert \lvert .\rvert \rvert_{\infty} $ is linearly homeomrphic (say by $T$) to both $X,\lvert \lvert .\rvert \rvert_{\infty} $ and $X,\lvert \lvert .\rvert \rvert_{\alpha} $,when I deduced that the inverse is continous,from the continuity of $T^{-1}$.

Comment: I mean both $T:(\mathbb{K}^{n},\lvert \lvert .\rvert \rvert_{\infty} ) \to (X,\lvert \lvert .\rvert \rvert_{\infty} )$ and $T:(\mathbb{K}^{n},\lvert \lvert .\rvert \rvert_{\infty} ) \to (X,\lvert \lvert .\rvert \rvert_{\alpha}) $ are linear homeomorphisms(so is the composition of the inverse of the first one with the second one which is the identity)